# Render Texture shows opposite view of camera when rendered?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using render texture (cube) to render what camera sees into it. However, the render texture shows me opposite side of cameras view (flipped) instead of what camera sees. I can rotate the render texture by hand but when I assign it to reflection probe, then it causes an issue since it shows opposite side. Any solution for this?

```
    void Update()
{
     renderTexture.isPowerOfTwo = true;          
     //Graphics.SetRenderTarget(renderTexture, 0, CubemapFace.PositiveZ);
     renderTexture.dimension = TextureDimension.Cube;
     camera.RenderToCubemap(renderTexture, 63);    
}
```

Comment: can you do a workaround and flip the sign of the wanted scale axis. e.g. horizontal flip would be from x to -x

Comment: On which platform (build target) is this?

Comment: @Remy its for Android.

Comment: Do you check your texture wrapmode? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureWrapMode.html

Comment: @joreldraw its a render texture.

Comment: your renderTexture is a texture. check this wrapmode

Comment: @joreldraw the texture is taken through camera from code as you can see the line camera.RenderToCubemap(renderTexture, 63); which is in realtime/runtime.

Comment: @Saif can you check this property of the texture object? not the realtime image… renderTexture.wrapmode

Comment: @joreldraw the wrap mode is set to "Clamp".

Comment: @Saif try changing the mode to MirrorOnce

Comment: @joreldraw I have tried using all the options, unfortunately it does nothing. I have to find a way to rotate it.

Comment: can you attach an image of your texture setup? showing the position and scale

Comment: @joreldraw I had posted in gamestackexchange as well, here is the link: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/178909/render-texture-shows-opposite-view-of-camera-when-rendered

Comment: Try 2 things, first one, instead of Update, use LateUpdate, if doesn't work, try to make the render on Start, the image resultant is flipped?

Comment: @Lotan Yes thats the problem, there is no problem in rendering, it renders it on a cube properly, only thing is its flipped on its z axis.